# Dropdown menu doesn't function in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I've modified a template [(here)](http://html5up.net/zerofour).  Nearly everything is working fine - mobile/tablet display, browser resize, etc.

the jQuery dropotron (version 1.4) dropdown menus on the navbar work fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE9 and IE11 (other versions untested), they don't work at all and so, the links nested in those menus are inaccessible.  The other scripts (tooltips and slideshows) I inserted display properly across the board - it is only the dropdowns that are wonky.

I'm somewhat out of my depth here - can anyone offer insight as to what may be happening?